# Hover effect for popular post widget in blogger

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm very much a newbie, but I'm been trying to figure out how to get a `hover effect` for my thumbnails for the popular posts widget in Blogger.

I have relatively large thumbnails and I want to have the title of the post appear on `hover`.

[Like this](http://www.lilypebbles.co.uk)

Can anyone help me with this? I've been trying to find a solution online, but have so far found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acutally the below can be simple achieved using `display: block;` and `none` but you won't be able to transit the element, hence, inorder to transit the element, we will hide it by using `opacity: 0;` and on `hover` we change it to `1`, and you can make the `background` opaque using `rgba()` and the smoothness using `transition`. Also, don't forget to make the parent element `position: relative;` as it holds an `absolute` positioned child element.

I've made the below example from scratch, you can take a look...

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k3nzC/)

```
div.wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.wrap img {
    display: block;
}

.title {
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    padding: 5px;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
}

div.wrap:hover .title {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much! This is probably a stupid question, but is there a way to align the title in the middle of the thumbnail?

Comment: @user3128743 assign some fixed width for the element on hover http://jsfiddle.net/k3nzC/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

suppose you have **Html Markup** like this:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    Iam the main content
    <div class="onhover">
        i am onhover content
    </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.thumbnail{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:Red;
}
.thumbnail:hover  .onhover {
    display: block;
}
```

see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5pdqL/)

so basically, what you want is to affect another element(with certain selector), when some other element is hovered, basic syntax is :

```
 sourceSelector:hover  targetSelector{ /*whatever css you want to apply*/}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used the suggestion above though and it worked. But thank you :)